# Simplest way to place cropped image on other image (Tikz)

Tags: tikz-pgf, scaling, crop, png

(I'm sure lots of ppl have had this exact same problem before, but I could not find it anywhere.)

I have two PNG files, A & B. Image A is like a frame, so it has an empty area in the middle. In this area I want to put some part of image B. I probably do not want to change the "aspect ratio", so same scaling of this part in both dimensions.

[image]

So the rectangle of size A,B starting at X,Y in image B should be occupying the 400x600 pixel space at 100,100 in image A (assume distance B = 3/2 * A).

I also want to scale image A arbitrarily. Currently I have (e.g.):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node {\includegraphics[witdh=0.5\textwidth]{image_a.png}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

How can I add the bit from image B (`image_b.png`) most easily. I have the feeling it should be possible without defining any new commands, or introducing any named variables.

**Clarification**: I want to be able to change the distances X,Y,A,B easily, so preferably they should each occur exactly once.

**More**: the cropped and scaled part from image B does not have to fit exactly in the area on image A. Also, the lengths do not have to be pixels. It can be metric or fractions or whatever. I just want a reasonably compact piece of code.

Comment: `\llap` + `\kern` + `\adjustbox` could help.

Comment: Yes. Images are boxes, boxes can be overlapped. Try `\includegraphics{example-image-a}
\llap{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}}` and see what happens.

Comment: \includegraphics does not pay attention to pixels.  Do you have the dimensions of image B?

Comment: Do you have the pixel spacing (which varies from PNG to PNG)?

Answer (score 2):

This shows one way to insert a cropped image into a hole in another image.

The saveboxes give us the dimensions of the images in something other than pixels.  The scope is used simply to  make the clip local.  The `\fill` is there just to show were the hole is.

Note that the clip is defined an terms of the hole in A.  All you have to do is move image B around and whatever is over the hole will be cropped to fit.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newsavebox{\tempboxa}
\newsavebox{\tempboxb}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}% start local definitions
  \savebox{\tempboxa}{\includegraphics[scale=2]{example-image-a}}% measure image A
  \savebox{\tempboxb}{\includegraphics[scale=2]{example-image-b}}% measure image B
  \node[inner sep=0pt] (A) {\usebox\tempboxa};
  \begin{scope}[shift=(A.south west)]
    \clip (0.25\wd\tempboxa, 0.8\ht\tempboxa) rectangle ++(0.5\wd\tempboxa,-0.6\ht\tempboxa);% hole in A
    \fill[red] (A.south west) rectangle (A.north east);% show hole in A (optional)
    \path (0.25\wd\tempboxa, 0.8\ht\tempboxa)% (left, top) of hole in A
      ++(-0.5\wd\tempboxb, -0.5\ht\tempboxb)% (-left, -top) of crop from B
      node[above right,inner sep=0pt]{\usebox\tempboxb};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was hoping for something simpler, but this is at least 50% better than what I did myself earlier.